# igraph half circle layout in R

Tags: geometry, igraph

I am trying various visualizations for an Igraph in R (version.3.3.1).
Currently my visualizing is as shown as below, 2 nodes (blue and green) in circular layout.

[Circular Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9DEj.png)

```
 visNetwork(data$nodes,data$edges) %>% visIgraphLayout(layout="layout_in_circle")
```

Now I want to have a semicircle structure instead of a full circle as in the pic. All blue nodes form a semicircle, green nodes another semicircle. Each semicircle separated by a small distance as well. How can i achieve this. I found grid package has an option for semicircle, but i couldnt make it work with igraph. Please provide some pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The `layout` argument accepts an arbitrary matrix with two columns and *N* rows if your graph has *N* vertices; all you need to do is to create a list of coordinates that correspond to a semicircle. You can make use of the fact that a vertex at angle *alpha* around a circle with radius *r* centered at (0, 0) is to be found at `(r * cos(alpha), r * sin(alpha))`. Since you are using R, *alpha* should be specified in radians, spaced evenly between 0 and *pi* (which corresponds to 180 degrees).